# Telnet - Connect and send message in one line

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

I'm looking for a one-line command that will connect to a telnet server (no authentication needed, it will accept any connection) and send text to the server after connection.

If this is not possible, is it possible to write a script that will do the same thing?

Comment: Please check [this](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/464761-send-a-text-to-telnet-port-using-single-line-command), [this](http://superuser.com/a/671033) and [this](http://superuser.com/a/671008), maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you can use [Netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) on the telnet port.

An example would go like so:

```
echo -n 'some string to telnet' | nc <server> 23
```

Comment: This just gives me the telnet welcome message, and not the result of my command

Answer (score 4):

With bash: replace "servername" by your telnet server:

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/tcp/servername/23
```

Comment: Using "/bin/bash" only, I believe: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html#DEVTCP